# building a custom histogram with highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to create a histogram with the data below, this is a sample of the data, the real object is much larger. I need the y-axis to be ‘Reads’ while the x-axis is a little more complex. The x-axis should be a range from 0-1, the bar on x-axis should be located corresponding to the ‘RankMetric’ variable. Is it possible to build a histogram like this with highcharts ? I’ve found this [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5eynnhty/) but I don’t know how set up the x-axis and plot the bars in the correct positions. Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

I can set the x-axis range with something like this, but how do I plot on the x-axis where according to the 'RankMetric' variable?

```
xAxis:{
 min:0,
 max:1,
 tickInterval: 0.1,
 crosshair: true
}
```

Data:

```
var obj = {
    "Reads":1721745,
    "Present":1,
    "RankMetric":0.397851,
    "organism_labels":"klebsiella_oxytoca"
},{
    "Reads":66529,
    "Present":1,
    "RankMetric":0.609935,
    "organism_labels":"staphylococcus_aureus"
},{
    "Reads":45563,
    "Present":1,
    "RankMetric":0.505084,
    "organism_labels":"legionella_longbeachae"
},{
    "Reads":83471,
    "Present":1,
    "RankMetric":0.669884,
    "organism_labels":"enterobacter_aerogenes"
}, {
    "Reads":1309077,
    "Present":1,
    "RankMetric":0.688673,
    "organism_labels":"pseudomonas_aeruginosa"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Data points needs to have `x` and `y` properties. Data should be sorted by `x` in ascending order. You could resolve this creating a parsing function that will allow you to meet the requirements. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4xjq56bh/

```
$(function() {
  var data = [{
    "Reads": 1721745,
    "Present": 1,
    "RankMetric": 0.397851,
    "organism_labels": "klebsiella_oxytoca"
  }, {
    "Reads": 66529,
    "Present": 1,
    "RankMetric": 0.609935,
    "organism_labels": "staphylococcus_aureus"
  }, {
    "Reads": 45563,
    "Present": 1,
    "RankMetric": 0.505084,
    "organism_labels": "legionella_longbeachae"
  }, {
    "Reads": 83471,
    "Present": 1,
    "RankMetric": 0.669884,
    "organism_labels": "enterobacter_aerogenes"
  }, {
    "Reads": 1309077,
    "Present": 1,
    "RankMetric": 0.688673,
    "organism_labels": "pseudomonas_aeruginosa"
  }];

    //data points needs to have x and y properties
  Highcharts.each(data, function(point, i) {
    point.y = point.Reads;
    point.x = point.RankMetric;
  });
  //data should be sorted by x in ascending order
    data = data.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.x - b.x;
  });

  $('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
      data: data,
      type: 'column',
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0
    }],
    xAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 1,
      tickInterval: 0.1,
      crosshair: true
    }
  });
});
```